# How to show a difference between the usage of '*' , '+' and '?' in grep?

Tags: grep, regex, wildcards

I understand that

```
'*' : The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
'?' : The preceding item is optional and will be matched, at most, once.
'+' : The preceding item will be matched one or more items
```

Can anyone give me an example of when there would be a difference while using grep? I was using egrep, but I tried to check if I could generate different outputs for these operators.

Comment: `?`  and `+` are part of extended regex, so you do need egrep for that to work

Comment: or `grep -E` in GNU grep :)

Comment: With GNU grep, the same *functionality* is available in both basic (BRE) and extended (ERE) regular expressions - it's just a matter of escaping. So for example in BRE, `?` matches a literal `?` while `\?` is the `{0,1}` quantifier; whereas in ERE it's the other way around i.e. `?` is the quantifier while `\?` matches a literal `?`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

make an example? try it out?

```
$ cat greppy
grp
grep
greep
```

zero or more e here

```
$ egrep 'gre*p' greppy
grp
grep
greep
```

zero or one e here

```
$ egrep 'gre?p' greppy
grp
grep
```

one or more e here

```
$ egrep 'gre+p' greppy
grep
greep
```

Comment: It's a pleasure, enjoy egrep ^_^ @lufork

Comment: `zero or one e here` or `optional e here`

Comment: That way of putting it may be clearer to some people @AvinashRaj :)